# URL parameters with GET request in django

Tags: python, regex, django

guys. I'm passing parameters via GET requests to my view. But it seems that django is not properly handling my URL.

With parameters longer than one char, it works, but if I use a single char, I get Page not found (404) error.

Example:

**Works:** http://localhost:8000/my_url/test

**Not found:** http://localhost:8000/my_url/t

urls.py code fragment:

```
url(r'^my_url/(?P<username>\w.+)/$', views.my_url, name='my_url'),
```

Is there any django restriction to the length of parameters passed via GET?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: try to remove dot from regex string `r'^my_url/(?P<username>\w+)/$'`

Comment: @Wonder, Thanks! Now it works. But how could I also accept dots in the  regular expression?

Comment: It seems to work with : `r'^my_url/(?P<username>[-\w.]+)/$'`. Is it right? Anyway, could you post your solution so I can accept it?

Comment: try to use [characted classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Character_classes). To allow all alphanumeric characters plus `_`, `.` and `-` replace `\w+` with `[A-Za-z0-9_.-]+`. UPD: yeah, looks like it should work too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove dot from regex string `r'^my_url/(?P<username>\w+)/$'`